# How to load devexpress xtrareport from file and connect data

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

I use devexpress xtrareports v.15 for winforms in my project.

I have invoice report. It has some text fields inside and one list. I connect data to sources in report ctor:

```
public InvoiceReport(InvoiceCommonData icd, List<ReportPosition> positions)
    {            
        InitializeComponent();            
        this.ReportCommonDataSource.DataSource = icd;
        this.positionsList.DataSource = positions;            
    }
```

When I print report as it was created in Visual Studio data is connected in right way. 
But I need to load different layouts for this report. I store report layout as repx file and try to load it from file at runtime:

```
InvoiceReport report = new InvoiceReport(model.GetCommonData(), model.GetPositions());
var filename = "D://InvoiceReport.repx";
report.LoadLayout(filename);
```

When I print report I see that common data (`icd`) was bound and is printed but list (`positions`) was not bound and it is empty table instead of real data. 
Question is how to load xtrareport layout from file and save all data connections?

Answer (score 0):

but i think u can try to replace connection of default repx file to your main connection becouse when we create repx file from report designer that time we set connection and repx save as default when we try to preview report with viewer file get default save connection so try to replace connection from required sql connection .

like `if (((DevExpress.DataAccess.Sql.SqlDataSource)devxReport.DataSource).ConnectionParameters != null) //change if connection exists in report 
                        {
                            ((DevExpress.DataAccess.Sql.SqlDataSource)devxReport.DataSource).ConnectionParameters = null;
                        }
                        ((DevExpress.DataAccess.Sql.SqlDataSource)devxReport.DataSource).ConnectionParameters =
                        new DevExpress.DataAccess.ConnectionParameters.CustomStringConnectionParameters(sqlConnectionString);`

Comment: Lalit Sharma thanks for answer. My problem is that when I load layout from the file report does not show List<ReportPositions>. When I don't load layout it works as it should.